# datepicker to command selected date

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

My html datepicker code:

```
    <div id="tarih" style="display:none;margin:auto;padding:10px">
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Click to Schedule..."></div>
```

I need a js code to do my js command in the selected date or time.
I tried this:

```
    var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
    alert(date);
```

but message is undefine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the datepicker method first, then get its value.  *Also you're using wrong selector, it is class so use `.`*

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

var date = $('.datepicker').val();
alert(date);
```

or using datepicker, **`onselect`** option

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                alert(dateText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found like this;

```
    $("#dateDiv input.datepicker").val()
```